# Why does jupyter fail to display displacy results?

Tags: spacy

I'm trying to run displacy in jupyter notebook but I get the following error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Code:

```
import en_core_web_sm
import spacy
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
from spacy import displacy

doc4 = nlp("The rat the cat the dog chased killed ate the malt")

displacy.render(doc4, style ='dep', jupyter = True)
```

However, the dependencies are appearing through the following code:

```
for x in doc4:
    print(x.text, x.pos_, x.dep_)
```

Can someone please guide as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc4 = nlp("The rat the cat the dog chased killed ate the malt")

displacy.render(doc4, style ='dep', jupyter = True)
```

(and your exact code also) works for me on `spacy==2.0.16`

You can try it out also on a jupyter running in the cloud, such as https://colab.research.google.com